# Fields with $x=-x\space \forall x\in F$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In todays linear algebra class, the professor gave us the following problem:

If $F$ is a field and $A\in M_{n\times n}(F)$ then there exists a symmetrical matrix $B\in M_{n\times n}(F)$ and an anti-symmetrical matrix $C\in M_{n\times n}(F)$ such that $A=B+C$.

I constructed $B$ and $C$ as follows (we write $A=(a_{ij})$, $B=(b_{ij})$ and $C=(c_{ij})$):

Let $b_{ij}=(a_{ij}+a_{ji})\cdot(1+1)^{-1}$ and 
$
c_{ij} =
\begin{cases}
0  & \text{if $i=j$} \\
(a_{ij}+a_{ji})\cdot(1+1)^{-1}-a_{ji} & \text{if $i>j$} \\
-c_{ji} & \text{if $i<j$}
\end{cases}
$

And we can verify that everything is satisfied.

But then I started to think of what happens if $1+1=0$ and soon noticed that it doesn't work generally for the binary field (in which $1+1=0$). So I decided to examine whether there are more fields in which this doesn't work.

If $1+1=0$ we can deduce that $x=-x\space \forall x\in F$. Are there fields in which this is satisfied other than the binary field; can we somehow characterize them? Is every such field an exception to the original problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think result is true only in fields where $2\neq 0$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Those are also known as the field of characteristic $2$. Another example of such a field has four elements $0,1,a,1+a$, where the addition is straightforward (under the premise that $1+1=a+a=0$) and a suitable multiplication can be obtained by deeming $a\cdot a=a+1$.
More generally, you can find such a field with $2^n$ elements for any $n\ge 1$ (incidentally, up to isomorphism you can find *only* one such field per $n$), and there are also infinite fields of characteristic $2$.

Fields of characteristic $2$ (and sometimes $3$) often require special care, just as you noticed in the problem at hand.

Answer (score 3):

A field where $1 + 1 = 0$ is called a field with *characteristic* two. In these fields, only symmetric matrices $A$ have such a decomposition, because the notions of antisymmetry and symmetry fall together.

I'm fairly sure there is no characterization of all field with characteristic two, but you can at least characterize all *finite* fields of characteristic two. See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1442777/259493).